# Validation not working if the values are already set when laoding the page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, thymeleaf

I'm building an aviation app that includes infor of passengers. I'm having a problem with Thymeleaf validation specifically when I bring up a page to UPDATE a passenger's details. The problem I've noticed is that my validation does not work if I populate the fields that can be changed with the values of the passenger I'm updating and change them to something that should throw a validation error e.g. leaving the name fields blank. It just throws an error: "field cannot be null". I noticed this because I have a form that's exactly the same as my UPDATE form except without the values already set. I'm not sure what I need to do to make the validation work.

My Passenger Controller

```
@GetMapping("/updatepassenger")
    public String showUpdatePassengerForm(@RequestParam("passengerId") Integer id, Model model, HttpSession session) {
        logger.info("Showing Update Passenger form!");
        session.setAttribute("name", "Update Passenger Form for " + passengerService.getPassengersById(id).getFullName());
        sessionHistoryService.addSession(session);

        Passenger passenger = passengerService.getPassengersById(id);
        List<Passenger.Gender> genders = Arrays.stream(Passenger.Gender.values()).toList();
        List<Passenger.Nationality> nationalities = Arrays.stream(Passenger.Nationality.values()).toList();

        PassengerViewModel passengerViewModel = new PassengerViewModel();
        passengerViewModel.setPassengerId(passenger.getPassengerId());
        passengerViewModel.setFirstName(passenger.getFirstName());
        passengerViewModel.setLastName(passenger.getLastName());
        passengerViewModel.setGender(passenger.getGender());
        passengerViewModel.setDateOfBirth(passenger.getDateOfBirth());
        passengerViewModel.setNationality(passenger.getNationality());

        model.addAttribute("passenger", passenger);
        model.addAttribute("genders", genders);
        model.addAttribute("nationalities", nationalities);
        model.addAttribute("passengerViewModel", passengerViewModel);

        return "updatepassenger";
    }

    @PostMapping("/updatepassenger")
    public String processUpdatePassengerForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("passengerViewModel") PassengerViewModel passengerViewModel, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpSession session) {
        logger.info("Updating " + passengerViewModel.toString());

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            modelErrors(result, model);
            return "/updatepassenger";
        } else {
            Passenger originalPassenger = passengerService.getPassengersById(passengerViewModel.getPassengerId());

            StringBuilder changes = new StringBuilder("Changes: ");
            if (!originalPassenger.getFirstName().equals(passengerViewModel.getFirstName())) {
                changes.append("First Name: ").append(originalPassenger.getFirstName()).append(" -> ").append(passengerViewModel.getFirstName()).append(" ");
            }
            if (!originalPassenger.getLastName().equals(passengerViewModel.getLastName())) {
                changes.append("Last Name: ").append(originalPassenger.getLastName()).append(" -> ").append(passengerViewModel.getLastName()).append(", ");
            }
            if (!originalPassenger.getGender().equals(passengerViewModel.getGender())) {
                changes.append("Gender: ").append(originalPassenger.getGender()).append(" -> ").append(passengerViewModel.getGender()).append(", ");
            }
            if (!originalPassenger.getDateOfBirth().equals(passengerViewModel.getDateOfBirth())) {
                changes.append("Date of Birth: ").append(originalPassenger.getDateOfBirth()).append(" -> ").append(passengerViewModel.getDateOfBirth()).append(", ");
            }
            if (!originalPassenger.getNationality().equals(passengerViewModel.getNationality())) {
                changes.append("Nationality: ").append(originalPassenger.getNationality()).append(" -> ").append(passengerViewModel.getNationality()).append(", ");
            }

            if (changes.length() > 9) {
                changes.setLength(changes.length() - 2);
                logger.info(changes.toString());

                session.setAttribute("name", "Updated Passenger Details for " + originalPassenger.getFullName() + ". " + changes);
                sessionHistoryService.addSession(session);
            } else {
                logger.info("No changes were made.");
                session.setAttribute("name", "No changes were made to Passenger " + originalPassenger.getFullName());
                sessionHistoryService.addSession(session);
            }

            passengerService.updatePassenger(passengerViewModel.getPassengerId(), passengerViewModel.getFirstName(), passengerViewModel.getLastName(), passengerViewModel.getGender(), passengerViewModel.getDateOfBirth(), passengerViewModel.getNationality());
        }
        return "redirect:/passengers";
    }

    private void modelErrors(BindingResult result, Model model) {
        result.getAllErrors().forEach(e -> logger.warn(e.toString()));

        List<Passenger.Gender> genders = Arrays.stream(Passenger.Gender.values()).toList();
        List<Passenger.Nationality> nationalities = Arrays.stream(Passenger.Nationality.values()).toList();

        model.addAttribute("genders", genders);
        model.addAttribute("nationalities", nationalities);
    }
```

my updatepassenger.html

```
<main>
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-6 pb-5">
            <form method="post" class="form" th:object="${passengerViewModel}">
                <h2 class="text-center" th:text="#{passenger_update}">Update Passenger</h2>
                <div>
                    <label th:for="firstName" th:text="#{passenger_firstName}">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" th:value="${passenger.firstName}">
                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" class="alert alert-danger">
                        <p th:errors="*{firstName}">The first name has errors!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label th:for="lastName" th:text="#{passenger_lastName}">Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" th:value="${passenger.lastName}">
                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}" class="alert alert-danger">
                        <p th:errors="*{lastName}">The last name has errors!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label th:for="gender" th:text="#{passenger_gender}">Gender:</label>
                    <select th:field="*{gender}" th:value="${passenger.gender}">
                        <option th:each="gen : ${genders}" th:value="${gen}" th:text="${gen}">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('gender')}" class="alert alert-danger">
                        <p th:errors="*{gender}">The last name has errors!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label th:for="dateOfBirth" th:text="#{passenger_dateOfBirth}">Date of Birth:</label>
                    <input type="date" th:field="*{dateOfBirth}">
                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('dateOfBirth')}" class="alert alert-danger">
                        <p th:errors="*{dateOfBirth}">The birthdate has errors!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label th:for="nationality" th:text="#{passenger_nationality}">Nationality:</label>
                    <select th:field="*{nationality}" th:value="${passenger.nationality}">
                        <option th:each="nat : ${nationalities}" th:value="${nat}" th:text="${nat.value}">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nationality')}" class="alert alert-danger">
                        <p th:errors="*{nationality}">The nationality has errors!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

My PassengerViewModel

```
public class PassengerViewModel {
    @NotNull
    private int passengerId;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=35, message = "Your first name should be between 3-35 characters long.")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[\\p{L} ]*$", message = "Your name should not contain numbers")
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=35, message = "Your last name should be between 3-35 characters long.")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[\\p{L} ]*$", message = "Your name should not contain numbers")
    private String lastName;
    private Passenger.Gender gender;
    @NotNull(message = "You should have a birth date.")
    @Past(message = "Your birth date should be in the past.")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    @NotNull
    private Passenger.Nationality nationality;
```

I get an error like:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'firstName' cannot be found on null
```

when i leave the changes blank on the name field.